# How to install PHP 5.6.8 on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, php

I am using Ubuntu and I'm quite new to this OS. How can I install PHP 5.6.8?

Comment: @kos the ppa in that answer is for version 5.5.x not 5.6.x

Comment: @Pabi Now it's for 5.6.x also

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ppa to install a newer version of PHP and keep it up to date.

Add the ppa to you system with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the relevant packages on your system with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Once it is finished check the version with `php5 -v`

Comment: The PPA listed here doesn't exist. I believe you want `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and then `sudo apt-get install php5.6`.